# Why is my code displaying a number 53 when I'm running my functions in c++

Tags: c++

My friend created a program that prints a triforce to the console, however when he ran his code he realized that it printed weird numbers instead of what was supposed to run.

The code looks like this:

```cpp
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

void ZeldaTriangle(int Size){
    for (int  row = 0; row < Size; row++)
    {
        for (int spa = 0; spa < (Size-row-1); spa++)
        {
            cout << (" ");
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < (row +1); col++)
        {
            cout << ("@");
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    }

}
void triforce_up (int Size, int character){
    for (int row = 0; row < (Size); row++)
    {
        for (int spa = 0; spa < (Size*2-row-1); spa++)
        {
            cout << (" ") << flush;
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < (row +1); col++)
        {
            cout << character << flush;
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
}
void triforce_down (int Size, int character){
    for (int row = 0; row < (Size); row++)
    {
        for (int spa = 0; spa < (Size-row-1); spa++)
        {
            cout << (" ");
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < (row +1); col++)
        {
            cout << character;
        }
        for (int spa = 0; spa < ((Size-row-1)*2); spa++)
        {
            cout << (" ");
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < (row +1); col++)
        {
            cout << character;
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
}
void print_ZeldaTriangle (int Size, int character){
    triforce_up (Size, character);
    triforce_down (Size, character);
}
int main() {
    int Size = 6;
    print_ZeldaTriangle(Size, '5');
}
```

It should display a triforce created with the number "5", but instead it shows this with the number 53.

```
           53
          5353
         535353
        53535353
       5353535353
      535353535353
     53          53
    5353        5353
   535353      535353
  53535353    53535353
 5353535353  5353535353
535353535353535353535353
```

I have attempted to change the "int character" to "string character" in order to prevent the error from happening but that displays a broken triforce that looks nothing like it should look like.

```
           5
          55
         555
        5555
       55555
      555555
     5          5
    55        55
   555      555
  5555    5555
 55555  55555
555555555555
```

Comment: learn [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And why are you printing a useless empty string in `cout << "" << endl;`?

Comment: int charcater; in argument 53 is ASCII value of '5'

Comment: thanks @VenkateshNandigama i thougth it had something to do with the number being inrerpreted as something else cause 4 gave me 52

Comment: @Rios `'4'` is 0x34 in ASCII which is 52 in decimal. You must print characters as `char`, not as `int`

Answer (score 3):

"void ZeldaTriangle(int Size)"

```
You don't need this function
```

when you convert char to int

your output is somewhat like this:

```
5                    5
55       or         55
555                555
5555              5555
55555            55555
555555          555555
```

then
your code is correct Syntactically it is printing what it is meant to print.
but logically you yourself is lacking basic imagination.

- either you can insert spaces in between or insert extra value to it

if you want output either like this or that...

```
     5                              5
    5 5                            555
   5 5 5                          55555
  5 5 5 5                        5555555
 5 5 5 5 5                      555555555
5 5 5 5 5 5                    55555555555
```

your code is good the only thing you need is some result imagination  :)

i have simplified the code: https://repl.it/repls/FluffyMildMenu

And
about the "53" error i don't know for sure but I think it is related to some charcater converted to int inside the code..

Comment: _it should display a triforce created with the number "5", but instead it shows this with the number 53_ — Your code prints 53 as well, not 5 as OP wants. BTW, answers that just contain links without detailed explanation are considered as bad answers and likely will be downvoted.

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica thanks for pointing out my mistake please check my edit response and if it still find any mistake do tell me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `5` as char but your functions accept integer value. When you pass a char value your functions will use ASCII value as int value. If you look at ASCII table '5' represents 53. Please refer link below:
https://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score 1):

I guess, as you are expecting in in the

```
print_ZeldaTriangle (int Size, int character) {

}
```

and inputing this

```
print_ZeldaTriangle(Size, '5');
```

The char is converted to int, which is bad as 
Char 5 when converted to int is 53
See this table for reference https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

So, to fix this, do this

```
int main() {
    int Size = 6;
    print_ZeldaTriangle(Size, 55);
}
```

EDIT:- Do 55, instead of 5

https://repl.it/repls/NoteworthyEnviousFactor

Comment: thanks man that is the right answer, but when I run it with the modifications I get the same error I described earlier where the triforce gets messed up and looks like this

Comment: I edited my answer to show what happens when I try changing the code

Comment: @Pulkit no, 55 will still not work, the triangle will be truncated at the top and the width of the output is still doubled

Comment: I guess, it works. If you ran the Repl above which I gave, it works there.
Are you compiling the code on the computer with gcc?

Answer (score 1):

53 is the ASCII value of character '5', change function signature to

```
 void triforce_up (int Size, char character)
 void triforce_up (int Size, char character)
```

Comment: when I do that the code shows something that does not look like the triforce, it's at the bottom of the question